# Java, Certificates in trustStores

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a root ca, A that issues an intermediate cert B that in turn issues a specific cert C

A -> B -> C

I start up a server which has these certs in it's p12 as the keychain

If I then have a java client which has all three certs in its trustStore it can access the cert over https successfully.

If cert C expires but I still have A & B in the trustStore, HTTPs is still successful.

If I remove A & C from the trustStore and just have B HTTPs is still successful.

My question is, if I only have A in the trustStore, the original Root CA, will HTTPs access still be successful?

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: That depends on how the server is configured. If it sends in it's SERVER_HELLO the certificate of B and C (which is the correct approach) then everything should still work if A is in the configured trust store on client side. But often server are misconfigured and only send C which then leads to the problem that A has no connection to C if B is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just adding the root certificate to your client trust store suffice to create the HTTPs successful connection. During the handshake, the certificate is validated from bottom-up way. It means that your Intermediate certificate must be signed by the root CA, and your leaf certificate must be signed by your intermediate CA. As long as your root CA is valid and present in your client's trust store, the connection will be successful.